# Perturbation property of Orthonormal basis for Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal basis for some Hilbert space. $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an orthonormal family with the property $\sum^\infty_{i\in I} \|e_i-f_i\|^2<\infty$, show that $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is also orthonormal basis.

I can think of for a $x$ with $(x,f_i)=0$ for all $i$, prove $x=0$. However, I don't know how to continue to the next step.

Comment: Are the bases countable?

Comment: It may not be countable.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is problem 12 in "A hilbert space problem book" by Halmos. But I currently don't have the book with me.

Comment: I think it is fairly straightforward to show that such an $x$ must be in the span of a finite number of $e_i$, but the remainder of the proof escapes me now.

Comment: Note that $e_i \ne f_i$ at at most a countable number of  $i$.

Comment: A simple version with $\sum\lVert e_i-f_i\rVert^2<1$: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967474/proving-that-if-sum-f-n-e-n-2-1-f-n-is-a-complete-sequence

Comment: If the $<1$ condition holds then it is straightforward, but I don't know how to deal with the $\not<1$ part.

Comment: https://archive.org/stream/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9330-6/10.1007-978-1-4684-9330-6#page/n187/mode/2up

Here is the book that @PhoemueX was referring to. It also has a really clean solution there too.

Comment: @Kevin That first solution looks surprisingly elementary. The second solution seems to be a variation on my answer below (or, perhaps more appropriately, my answer seems to be a variation on the second solution).

Answer (score 1):

Let $H$ denote the given Hilbert space. As noted by copper.hat, one may assume $I=\mathbb{N}$. First observe that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lvert 1 - \langle e_i,f_i\rangle\rvert^2 + 2\sum_{i=1}^\infty \sum_{j=i+1}^\infty \lvert \langle f_j,e_i\rangle\rvert^2 = \sum _{i = N + 1} ^{\infty} \lVert e _i - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \langle e_j,f_i\rangle e_j \rVert ^{2} = \sum _{i = 1} ^{\infty} \lVert e _i - f _i \rVert ^{2}.
$$
Pick $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
\sum _{i = N + 1} ^{\infty} \lVert e _i - f _i \rVert ^{2} &< 1/2, \\
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty \lvert \langle f_j,e_i\rangle\rvert^2 &< 1/2.
\end{align*}

Define $E_N=\overline{\mbox{span}}(e_{N+1},e_{N+2},\ldots)$ and $F_N=\overline{\mbox{span}}(f_{N+1},f_{N+2},\ldots)$. For a closed subspace $A\subseteq H$, let $P_A$ denote the orthogonal projection onto $A$ in $H$. Then we find
\begin{align*}
\lVert P_{E_N} - P_{F_N} \rVert_{\text{HS}}^2 & = \sum_{i=1}^N \lVert P_{F_N}e_i \rVert^2 + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty \lVert e_i - P_{F_N}e_i \rVert^2 \\
& = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty \lvert\langle f_j,e_i\rangle \rvert^2 + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty \lVert e_i - P_{F_N}e_i \rVert^2 \\
& \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=N+1}^\infty \lvert\langle f_j,e_i\rangle \rvert^2 + \sum_{i=N+1}^\infty \lVert e_i - f_i \rVert^2 < 1.
\end{align*}
Thus, we have
$$
\lVert P_{E_N^\perp} - P_{F_N^\perp} \rVert_{\text{HS}}^2 = \lVert P_{E_N} - P_{F_N} \rVert_{\text{HS}}^2 < 1.
$$
But this implies that $\dim F_N^\perp = \dim E_N^\perp = N$, and therefore $F_N^\perp = \mbox{span}(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$. Which was what we wanted!