# A question about proving 'can fail' problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I came across this question: [Proving that if $\sum\|f_n-e_n\|^2< 1$, $\{f_n\}$ is a complete sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/967474/proving-that-if-sum-f-n-e-n-2-1-f-n-is-a-complete-sequence) today. The proof is clear, however I just have a question that if $
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\|f_{n}-e_{n}\right\|^{2}\leq1
$, that is, if the equality holds, then $\{f_n\}$ may not be complete. This seems straight forward but I'm kinda stuck here. How to formally prove that? Can I just say that $
\left.||g|\right|^{2} \leq S\|g\|^2
$ when $S=1$  is valid for any $g$, hence $g$ don't have to be a zero vector ?
I seem to have trouble understanding the 'may not' part, since the inequality doesn't seem enough to determine $g$, what if there is other constraints? How to prove this type of 'may not' or 'can fail' problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What you suggest is not sufficient for a proof - you would need to find a counter example. However, the result might be generalized to $\sum \Vert f_n - e_n \Vert^2 < \infty$ instead of $< 1$. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257099/perturbation-property-of-orthonormal-basis-for-hilbert-space?noredirect=1&lq=1) question seems relevant

Comment: But $f_n$ are orthogonal basis indicates they are complete, right?

Comment: Can I just say that I have zero vector in one direction, let's say $f_1=0$, and the rest of $f_n=e_n$, then the closed span is not complete? Is that a counterexample?

Comment: Yes, an othonormal basis is complete. The question I linked to refers to an orthonormal set.

Comment: No, this is not a counterexample. It does not satisfy $\sum \Vert f_n - e_n \Vert^2 = 1$.

Comment: @G.ChiusoleBut he showed that this orthogonal family is actually an orthonormal basis, which means that for any $
\sum\left\|f_{n}-e_{n}\right\|^{2}<\infty
$ $f_n$ is complete, including $
\sum\left\|f_{n}-e_{n}\right\|^{2}=1
$

Comment: Yes, he does. But he assumes the $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ to be an orthonormal set. Not just any set. This can quite possibly generalized, but I did not look into it.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Oh I missed that part. sry